# Create-react-app frontend, Laravel backend registration 419 unknown status

Tags: laravel, create-react-app, laravel-authentication

I've got a create-react-app client and a Laravel back-end with the out of the box Auth::routes(). I'm trying to send a POST request to the register route from a function in my CRA redux store but keep getting the below error:

`POST http://localhost:8000/register 419 (unknown status)`

At first I was getting the cors preflight response error so I'm now making use of [this](https://github.com/fruitcake/laravel-cors) package.

Things I've tried since:

- changing from using fetch() in the client to axios.
- attaching the csrf-token when sending the request.
- changing the Auth::routes() from web to api.

** UPDATED TO SHOW TOKEN **

```
export const signup = (name: string, email: string, password: any, repeatPassword: any) => {
    return async (dispatch: any) => {

const data = {
     name,
     email,
     password,
     returnSecureToken: true
}

const response = await fetch(
    'http://localhost:8000/register',
     {   
       method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json;charset=UTF-8',
             "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
             'X-XSRF-TOKEN': (() => {
                        const name = 'XSRF-TOKEN';
                        const cookies = '; ' + document.cookie;
                        const parts: any = cookies.split('; ' + name + '=');
    
                        const value = parts.length == 2 ? parts.pop().split(';').shift() : null
    
    
    
                        console.log('>>> XSRF-TOKEN', value)
    
                        return value
                    })(),
         },
                body: JSON.stringify(data)
      }
   );
  }
}
```

Back-end cors.php

```
'paths' => ['*'],

    'allowed_methods' => ['*'],

    'allowed_origins' => ['*'],

    'allowed_origins_patterns' => [],

    'allowed_headers' => ['*'],

    'exposed_headers' => [],

    'max_age' => 0,

    'supports_credentials' => false,
```

And in routes/web.php:

```
Auth::routes();
```

Get requests to a custom controller are fine as I've tried this to test out of it could hit the api at all, it's just the register route it isn't able to hit for some reason. Is it possible at all to send a request to laravel's register route from a client?

Thanks.

Comment: are you including the CSRF token with the post data? if this isn't an API route then it will be looking for the CSRF token when using POST, PUT, PATCH, etc.

Comment: @lagbox edited to show. I had been using this approach to test it out as I saw it on another thread, but when I do that I get an invalid payload error. I had also tried adding it as a meta tag in my index.html and grabbing its content attribute from my component, but that also resulted in a 419.